# Sort date string in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I wanted to sort an array of objects using js. Here is what I have implemented.

```
var employees = []
employees[0] = {
    retiredate: "01/12/2014"
}
employees[1] = {
    retiredate: "29/01/2015"
}
employees[2] = {
    retiredate: "05/12/2014"
}
employees[3] = {
    retiredate: "08/12/2014"
}
employees[4] = {
    retiredate: "11/12/2014"
}
employees[5] = {
    retiredate: "14/01/2015"
}
employees[6] = {
    retiredate: "03/12/2014"
}
employees[7] = {
    retiredate: "16/01/2015"
}
employees[8] = {
    retiredate: "19/01/2015"
}
employees[9] = {
    retiredate: "22/01/2015"
}
employees[10] = {
    retiredate: "28/01/2015"
}
employees[11] = {
    retiredate: "23/01/2015"
}
employees[12] = {
        retiredate: "15/01/2015"
    }
    //console.log(periodesSorted);

console.log("START  ... ")
employees.sort(function(a, b) {
    var dateA = new Date(a.retiredate),
        dateB = new Date(b.retiredate)
    return dateA - dateB //sort by date ascending
})

for (ind2 = 0; ind2 < employees.length; ind2++) {
    console.log(employees[ind2].retiredate)
}
console.log("End  ... ")
```

In firefox the array of retiredate is well sorted.

In chrome, I have the following results

```
01/12/2014
 15/01/2015
05/12/2014
08/12/2014
11/12/2014
14/01/2015
29/01/2015
16/01/2015
19/01/2015
22/01/2015
28/01/2015
23/01/2015
03/12/2014
```

The results are not sorted. Where did I go wrong in the codes? 
Can anyone suggest a fix for this ?

Regards

Comment: You cannot produce a valid date from a string in dd/mm/yyyy format; `03/12/2014` would result in March 12th, `23/01/2015` is invalid. Use mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: You could sort ist by transform the dates to an integer, which represents the days between 1.1.1970 and the actual date - and then let a sort algorithm do the rest - to then transform them back

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
new Date(a.retiredate)
```

Make it like this to convert dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd before creating the date:

```
new Date(a.retiredate.replace( /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$3-$2-$1") );
```

Working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/inanda/csz56b0q/1/

Comment: I suggest instead to replace with `$3-$2-$1` as that makes it an ISO 8601 format, which is documented to be supported. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

In our case you need convert date to format `mm/dd/yyyy`, you can do it like this

```
employees.sort(function(a, b) {
  var toDate = function (date) {
    var res = date.split('/');
    return new Date(res[2], res[1], res[0]).getTime();

    // getTime returns the number of milliseconds
    // or you can use + before new Date..
  };

  return toDate(a.retiredate) - toDate(b.retiredate);
})
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/yodasu/3/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
employees.sort(function (d1, d2) {
  function parseDate(str) {
    var parts = str.match(/(\d+)/g);
    // assumes M/D/Y date format
    return new Date(parts[2], parts[0]-1, parts[1]); // months are 0-based
  }
  return parseDate(d1.retiredate) - parseDate(d2.retiredate);
});
```

Here Is example [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/s8HwU/166/)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would avoid all the re-parsing & date construction (84 times in your sample);

```
// prepare the data by appending a date from a reformatted string
for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    var dateString = employees[i].retiredate;
    employees[i]._date = new Date(dateString.substr(6, 4) + "-" + dateString.substr(3, 2) + "-" + dateString.substr(0, 2));
}

// sort without conversion
employees.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a._date - b._date;
})
```